# How to sort a List collection of classes with properties in them?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting

I have a List of classes in my collection like

```
List<MyClass> test = new List<MyClass>();
```

In my classes I have just some properties

```
public string id {get; set;}
public DateTime date {get; set;}
```

Now I make these classes by getting some queries from 2 different database tables. I then take those 2 results from the database tables and using a foreach loop I make a new MyClass object and stick it in my "test" collection.

Now once all these classes are put in the the list collection. I want to sort through them and order the classes by the "date" property.

How could I do this? I can't order then right when I get them from the database since I am getting them from 2 different database tables and ordering them separately would only make it ordered in for each section but table one might have 12/12/2009 and so might table two. So they need to be ordered together.

So can I some how use linq or something to order them?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about:

```
list.Sort((x,y) => DateTime.Compare(x.date, y.date));
```

which sorts the existing list, or:

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(x=>x.date).ToList();
```

which creates a second list.

Comment: Ya as I mentioned below I tried to do the second way before I posted but did not use .ToList() So orderBy always creates a new list while sort does not?

Comment: Yes.  List.Sort sorts the list in place, so the original list is altered.  LINQ (the second method) creates a new enumerable.  By adding "ToList", you turn it into a List<MyClass> instead of IEnumerable<MyClass>.  If you're just going to use the results in a foreach loop, you can leave the "ToList()" method off.

Comment: can we do orderby for even a property of type string called "Name"...like below..... var list2 = list1.where(o=>o.Name.contains("test")).orderby(o=>o.Name).Take(10).toList();

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort them in place, you can use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
test.Sort( (l,r) => l.date.CompareTo(r.date) );
```

If you want to sort them into a new result set, LINQ is very nice:

```
var sortedResults = from mc in test
                    order by mc.date
                    select mc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your classes in your list, and the list is complete:

```
List<MyClass> testList = new List<MyClass>();
// populate the list...

var orderedList = testList.OrderBy( x => x.date ).ToList();
```

Comment: Ah I tried that but did not put .ToList() behind it. I seen some people use the compare function does that bring any advantages or anything?