# Sort List<T> by count of property of inner list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm trying to find a way to sort a list of objects I have based on a property (which is a list) of a property (another list).  Here's my objects:

**ComputerCard:**

```
public partial class ComputerCard : XtraUserControl
{
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    public List<Role> CardRoles = new List<Role>();
    //More properties that are omitted for brevity.
}
```

**Role:**

```
public class Role
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public List<DependentRole> DependentRoles { get; set; }
    public List<AppToRun> AppsToRun { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        if (AppsToRun == null)
            AppsToRun = new List<AppToRun>();

        if (DependentRoles == null)
            DependentRoles = new List<DependentRole>();
    }
}
```

**DependentRole:**

```
public class DependentRole
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my main form, I have declared the following:

```
List<ComputerCard> cards
```

As you can see, `cards` can have 1 or many `Role`, and each `Role` can have 0 or many `DependentRole`.  So given this list, I need a way to order it by `DependentRole.Count` in descending order.  I looked at and tried the recommendation from this [SO Link - How to sort list of list by count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301814/how-to-sort-list-of-list-by-count) but didn't have much luck.

```
List<ComputerCard> cardz = cards.Where(c => c.LookUpEdit.EditValue != null).ToList();
cardz.Sort((a, b) => a.CardRoles.Count - b.CardRoles.Count);
```

**Results:**

```
Card: File Server
  Role: Server
    Dependent Roles: 0

Card: VCS Gateway
  Role: File Server
    Dependent Roles: 0

Card: domain.pc1.domain
  Role: Pilot 1
    Dependent Roles: 3

Card: domain.pc5.domain
  Role: Local Controller
    Dependent Roles: 1

Card: domain.pc3.domain
  Role: Pilot 3
    Dependent Roles: 3

Card: domain.pc4.domain
  Role: Ground Controller
    Dependent Roles: 2
```

And what I need the results to look like is this:

```
Card: File Server
  Role: Server
    Dependent Roles: 0

Card: VCS Gateway
  Role: File Server
    Dependent Roles: 0

Card: domain.pc5.domain
  Role: Local Controller
    Dependent Roles: 1

Card: domain.pc4.domain
  Role: Ground Controller
    Dependent Roles: 2

Card: domain.pc1.domain
  Role: Pilot 1
    Dependent Roles: 3

Card: domain.pc3.domain
  Role: Pilot 3
    Dependent Roles: 3
```

Notice how the cards are listed by the count of DependentRoles.  Can this be achieved?  If so, how?

**UPDATE**

Using Amit's answer, I get the correct results but neglected the requirement of listing cards with multiple Roles in ascending order on DependentRoles.Count:

```
Card: File Server
    Role: Server
        Dependent Roles: 0

Card: VCS Gateway
    Role: File Server
        Dependent Roles: 2

Card: domain.pc1.domain
    Role: Pilot 1
        Dependent Roles: 3

Card: domain.pc4.domain
    Role: Pilot 1
        Dependent Roles: 3

Card: domain.pc2.domain
    Role: Pilot 1
        Dependent Roles: 3

Card: domain.pc5.domain
    Role: Pilot 1
        Dependent Roles: 3
    Role: Ground Controller
        Dependent Roles: 2

Card: domain.pc3.domain
    Role: Pilot 1
        Dependent Roles: 3
    Role: Ground Controller
        Dependent Roles: 2
    Role: VCS Gateway
        Dependent Roles: 0
```

Comment: Why not just `cardz.OrderBy(a => a.CardRoles.Count)`?

Comment: Since you have list of lists, you need to define what do you mean by inner list count. Apparently it's not only one, so you have to define some aggregate, like `Sum`, `Min`, `Max` etc.

Comment: Your example doesn't show what happens when a Card has multiple Roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the following- (if not then let me know)

```
List<ComputerCard> SortedCards = cards.OrderBy(                    
                   x => x.CardRoles.Sum(y => y.DependentRoles.Count))
                   .ToList();
foreach (var item in SortedCards)
{
    item.CardRoles = item.CardRoles
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.DependentRoles.Count).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This works great, but one thing I didn't take into account is if there are multiple Roles in a card, then I'd like the Roles to be listed by DependentRole.Count only in ascending order.  See my updated question for the results and the Cards named domain.pc5.domain and domain.pc3.domain will show you what it's doing now (Descending order).

Comment: @Robert foreach should order the roles  in descending order now.

Comment: That made the difference.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var ordered = cards.SelectMany(c => c.CardRoles.Select(r => new { Card = c, Role = r }))
      .OrderBy(a => a.Role.DependentRoles.Count)
      .ThenBy(a => a.Card.ComputerName)
      .ThenBy(a => a.Role.RoleName)
      .Select(c => c.Card);
```